# GradientDescentOptimizer error keeps growing

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I am trying to do a linear regression using a `GradientDescentOptimizer`, but the result I'm getting is that my error grows really fast, and then overflows.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample result of my error at each iteration:

```
2163732.5
1274220300000000.0
7.274338e+23
4.141076e+32
inf
inf
...
```

Here's my code

```
import os 
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv').values
x_vals = data[:,1:]
y_vals = data[:,0]
n_dim = x_vals.shape[1]

W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1, n_dim]))
b = tf.Variable(0.5, dtype=tf.float32)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

prediction = tf.reduce_sum(W * X) + b
error = Y - prediction
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    init = tf.initializers.global_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range (0, 100):

        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_vals, y_vals, test_size=100, train_size=100)

        _, loss_result = sess.run([optimizer, loss], {X: x_train, Y: y_train})
        print(loss_result)
```

I generated my data with the formula `y = (0.5 * x_1) + (3 * x_2)` so it should be perfectly linear (ignoring rounding errors):  It looks like this:

```
y,x_1,x_2
28,9,8
24,6,7
31,9,9
34,8,10
24,12,6
...
```

[Here's my full data](https://github.com/Toreth/Datasets/blob/master/test.csv)

Answer (score 1):

Your gradient was overshooting the minima hence was exploding. You should try increasing the number epochs and decrease the learning rate to the order of 1e-5 or even lesser something like 1e-7 , 1e-8 . It doesn't overshoot for the values epoch = 100000 and learning rate = 0.0000003.

Comment: Thank you, I made those changes and the error no longer overflows.  However, the error still bounces around from around 60 to around 90 and doesn't converge to a solution.  Do you know why that's happening?  I think I must be doing something wrong in my calculations.

Comment: Not sure about that but you can try multiple things. 1) Play around with the epochs and learning rate. 2)  You try initializing the weights with random values or use some kind of initializer instead of initializing it with fixed values.  3) Do an analysis on the data , check for outliers and ways you can fix it. You can also normalize your data before putting it in the model.